# How to bind events on raw (imported) html via code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm importing a html containing SVG code and render it via v-html directive, but I need to bind click events to the a-html tags from that file which aren't part of my template.

- How do I get all the a-tag from that imported file?
- And how do I bind events to these elements whitout using v-on directive?

The template

```
            <v-flex mt-2 px-0 xs6 
                    ref="map_svg"
                    v-html="mapHTML">
            </v-flex>
```

Snippet of the imported file

```
<svg>
  <g>
     <g>
        <a target="_blank" xlink:href="url to a subsite" >
            <!-- content path which shows a circle -->
         </a>
     </g>
     <g>
        <a target="_blank" xlink:href="url to a differnt subsite" >
            <!-- content path which shows a circle -->
         </a>
     </g>

     <!-- many more elements like shown on the top -->
  </g>
</svg>
```

I would need to bind an click event to these a-tags and remove or overwrite the xlink:href attribute so the click won't open a different tab in the browser.

## Edit

I ended up doing it like this:

```
  mounted() {

    const that = this;
    const links = this.$el.querySelectorAll('#map_svg svg > g > g > a');

    links.forEach(el => {
      const url = el.getAttribute('xlink:href');
      if (url) {
        // el.addEventListener('click', that.stationClick(url));
        el.onclick = function (){
          that.stationClick(url);
        }
        el.removeAttribute('xlink:href');
      }
      el.removeAttribute('target');
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind click events on those elements after you have loaded your svg:

```js
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      mapHTML: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async loadSvg() {
      // Here, you load your svg
      this.mapHTML = `
        <a href="https://google.fr" _target="blank">Google</a> 
      `;

      // You need to use $nextTick in order to wait for the DOM to be refreshed
      this.$nextTick(() => { 
        this.bindClicks() // You bind click events here
      })

    },
    bindClicks () {
      // You search for all the a tags in your svg_container
      this.$refs.map_svg.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(el => {
        el.removeAttribute('_target') // You remove the _target attribute
        el.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick) // You bind an event listener to the element
      })
    },
    handleClick (e) {
      // You handle the click like you would normally do
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.
The <code> el.addEventListener()</code> for some reason didn't work, had to use <code>el.onclick = function () { // ...  }</code> 
I wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ref` you set and plain JS to bind to the tags.

```
this.$refs.map_svg.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', this.callback) )
```

Comment: Ah yeah, for some reason I though there should a vue.js way to do it and I missed that I could use plain JS to do it :D
Thanks